# How can to change same css style after hover parent to child tag element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, click

I have html code segments is below,

```
<div class="div-builder">
    <div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="/photos/20/Apple-Logo-icon.png" width="50" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <i>sub-title</i>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ...</p>
</div>
```

I need to do that when I will hover over the .div-builder class then its css background color will be change according to the below css,

```
.div-builder{ background-color: lightyellow; }
```

And the result will be such like the image below,
[image]

Again when I will hover over the `<img>` tag then it also should be change background color as lightyellow but at the same time .div-builder class background color won't be as lightyellow. Result will be such like the image below,
[image]

Here, `<img>` tag can be any level child of the .div-builder class. This `<img>` tag is not same level child tag according to the above HTML code segment, it can be varied any level child tag.

Same way, `<h3>` or `<i>` or `<p>` tag background color should be change as lightyellow when it will be hove over by the mouse. But at the same time .div-builder class background color won't be change as lightyellow. After hover over the `<p>` tag the result will be following,
[image]

How can I do this hover over effect by CSS?

Or

How can I do this click event instead of hover effect by jQuery?

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to achieve. can you post a picture of the desired result? you want all the background changed or all but div-builders background changed?

Comment: Okay, so you want the background of the CHILDREN of .div-builder to change background on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro here is your answer I hope you like. 
https://codepen.io/Ultra_Hopeful/pen/MWawrGK

```js
function hoveref() {
      $(".div-builder")
        .find("h3,i,p,img,a")
        .hover(
          function () {
            $(this).css("background", "SpringGreen");
            $(".div-builder").css("background", "initial");
          },
          function () {
            $(this).css("background", "initial");
            $(".div-builder").css("background", "SpringGreen");
          }
        );
    }
    function hoverafter() {
      $(".div-builder").css("background", "initial");
    }
```

```html
<div class="div-builder" onmouseenter="hoveref()" onmouseleave="hoverafter()">
      <div>
        <a href="#" width="100%">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/300" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <h3 class="">Title</h3>
        <i>sub-title</i>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ...</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(173, 173, 173, 0.9);
}


.div-builder {
    background: white;
}

.div-builder div:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="div-builder">
        <div>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://static.javatpoint.com/htmlpages/images/html-tutorial.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>

    <div>
         <i>sub-title</i>    
    </div>
        <hr/>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem Ispsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I won't add extra wrapping <div> inside the parent .div-builder class div. How can I do this?

Comment: @OptimusPrime can you add class names?

Comment: It will be better without adding class name in the tag.

Comment: @OptimusPrime then i think you have to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly your task is change background of element when your cursor is hovering over it? 
is so its really simple task : 
its can be achieved by CSS
1.add to the css ":hover" 
like that (p is for paragraph)

```
 p:hover {
      background-color: red;
      font-size: 20px;
 }
```

2.done:) [change the p to any id \ class that you want ]

[changing background at hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyeuA.gif)
 i hoped that helped

if you want change capsule elements when hovering one

```
.hoverME:hover { background:red; }
```

and then warp the elements with div

```
<div  class="hoverME">
<p>i will be warrped by red background</p>
<p>me too!! y</p>
</div>
```